# Binding mousewheel returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I am testing the following code:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  alert(e.wheelDelta);
});
```

Every time I move the mousehweel, I get "undefined".  Can anyone help with this as I am trying to capture the mousewheel and move a div based on it.

Comment: Try `console.log(e)` inside your bind function. That will show you what properties it holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to do a little bit more work to get it working in all browsers - or try the [jquery-mousewheel extension](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

If the extension still does not work properly, you might try this modified version I created a while ago:

```
/* jquery.mousewheel.min.js
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Brandon Aaron (http://brandonaaron.net)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 * Thanks to: http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/ for some pointers.
 * Thanks to: Mathias Bank(http://www.mathias-bank.de) for a scope bug fix.
 *
 * Version: 3.0.2
 * 
 * Requires: 1.2.2+
 */
(function(c) {
    var a = [ "DOMMouseScroll", "mousewheel" ];
    c.event.special.mousewheel = {
        setup : function() {
            if (this.addEventListener) {
                for ( var d = a.length; d;) {
                    this.addEventListener(a[--d], b, false)
                }
            } else {
                this.onmousewheel = b
            }
        },
        teardown : function() {
            if (this.removeEventListener) {
                for ( var d = a.length; d;) {
                    this.removeEventListener(a[--d], b, false)
                }
            } else {
                this.onmousewheel = null
            }
        }
    };
    c.fn.extend({
        mousewheel : function(d) {
            return d ? this.bind("mousewheel", d) : this.trigger("mousewheel")
        },
        unmousewheel : function(d) {
            return this.unbind("mousewheel", d)
        }
    });
    function b(f) {
        var d = [].slice.call(arguments, 1), g = 0, e = true;
        if (f.wheelDelta) {
            g = f.wheelDelta / 120
        }
        if (f.detail) {
            g = -f.detail / 3
        }
        // I had to move the following two lines down, probably because of jQuery update
        f = c.event.fix(f || window.event);
        f.type = "mousewheel";
        f.pageX = f.originalEvent.pageX;
        f.pageY = f.originalEvent.pageY;
        d.unshift(f, g);
        return c.event.handle.apply(this, d)
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I just tested it in Firefox and Chrome, but I don't know whether it works in other browsers. Usage:

```
$('element').mousewheel(function(e, delta) { alert(delta); });
```

Comment: `$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaY, deltaX) {
 alert(delta);
});`
I've added this extension and tested the following code(in Chrome).  I get the same data.  Firefox doesn't seem to detect it at all.

Comment: `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta` seems to return the data I want in Chrome.  IE and Firefox seem unresponsive(dont even trigger the event).

Comment: Oh, I remember there was some bug I had to fix when I used it. See the code above, it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the following snippet:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document)
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        if(delta > 0) {
                    // Scrolling down
        } else {
                    // Scrolling up
        }
    });
});
```

This requires the jquery mousewheel extention and works in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution was to change jquery version from 1.7.x to 1.9.x